# WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration

Tags: parsing, jboss

I am new to Jboss world and running JBOSS and getting following error while starting.

```
    =========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /home/manish/Desktop/ometap/wildfly-10.0.0.Final

  JAVA: java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n

=========================================================================

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by __redirected.__SAXParserFactory (file:/home/manish/Desktop/ometap/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/jboss-modules.jar) to constructor com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of __redirected.__SAXParserFactory
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
13:34:35,267 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.1.Final
13:34:35,627 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
13:34:35,798 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) starting
13:34:36,608 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:131)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:356)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:299)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module org.wildfly.extension.core-management
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.parseExtensions(ExtensionXml.java:155)
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml$DefaultExtensionHandler.parseExtensions(StandaloneXml.java:126)
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_4.readServerElement(StandaloneXml_4.java:218)
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_4.readElement(StandaloneXml_4.java:141)
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:103)
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:49)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:123)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.parseExtensions(ExtensionXml.java:147)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.loadModule(ExtensionXml.java:196)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.access$000(ExtensionXml.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml$1.call(ExtensionXml.java:127)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml$1.call(ExtensionXml.java:124)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.wildfly.extension.core-management:main
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:223)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.loadModule(ExtensionXml.java:178)
    ... 8 more

13:34:36,611 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
13:34:36,615 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-1) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested.
13:34:36,681 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) stopped in 34ms
```

How can i fix above error?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Java 9+ I'd suggest using at least WildFly 15. WildFly 17.0.1.Final is the latest release and does work with Java 9+.

If you are stuck on WildFly 10, I'd suggest using Java 1.8 instead.